Как правильно использовать webAppData в telebot?
Есть веб страница с кнопкой и счетчиком кликов на эту кнопку. Счетчик засчитывает количество кликов в переменную. Из этой переменной хочу сделать вывод в самого бота на telebot. Как вывести через web_app_data.data я понял, но выводится в формате {"clicks":1}. Как вывести только числовое значение? Почему по нажатию кнопки закрывается веб страничка в телеграмме и выводится сообщение о том, что данные пользователя были переданы боту, как это решить? Возможно есть аналогичные способы вывода данных из веб страницы в бота? Есть ли какие то советы по моему html или css?


<script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>BestShop</title>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;500&display=swap');
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .image-coin {
      margin-top: 10%;
      margin-left: 25%;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-image: url('https://i.sstatic.net/fzSbVP56.jpg');
      background-size: 111%;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
    <button id="coin_click" class="image-coin" onClick="onClick()"></button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
  <script>
    let tg = window.Telegram.WebApp;
    let coin_click = document.getElementById("coin_click")

    var clicks = 0;

    function onClick() {
      clicks += 1;
      document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    }

    coin_click.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let data = {
        clicks: clicks
      }

      tg.sendData(JSON.stringify(data));
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>



import telebot

from config import token
from telebot import types
from telebot.types import WebAppInfo

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token, parse_mode=None)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button = types.KeyboardButton(text="Тестовая страница", web_app=WebAppInfo(weburl))
    keyboard.add(button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет :)", reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['web_app_data'])
def web_app(webAppMes):
    print(webAppMes.web_app_data.data)


bot.infinity_polling(none_stop=True)


Для начала преобразуйте данные webAppMes.web_app_data.data из строки в словарь. Для этого импортируем в код модуль json import json, затем преобразовываем, используя метод loads().
И тогда получается:
data = json.loads(webAppMes.web_app_data.data) # Теперь это словарь

print(data['clicks']) # Получаем содержимое

Что касается закрытия страницы. Создайте отдельную Telegram кнопку, которая будет появляться после первого нажатия на монетку:
function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  if (!tg.MainButton.isVisible){ // Проверяем, что пользователь не видит кнопку
     tg.MainButton.show(); // Отображаем кнопку
  }
}

А затем обработайте её нажатие и вот уже после зарегистрированного нажатия смело отправляйте данные.
Telegram.WebApp.onEvent('mainButtonClicked', function() {
    tg.sendData(JSON.stringify({clicks: clicks}));
});


Не очень понял какого характера нужно создать кнопку

Вам нужно отследить нажатие на телеграмовскую кнопку MainButton.  Реализуется таким образом: Telegram.WebApp.onEvent('mainButtonClicked', callback)

а где именно с этим работать?

В блоке, где находится ваш javascript код.

Вот полная документация Telegram с методами работы https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#mainbutton

Для него нужно получается создавать callback функцию?

Обновил ответ, последний блок кода поместите в конце.

Теперь у меня появилась кнопка "Продолжить", по нажатию на которую закрывается веб страница и только тогда данные передаются в бота

Может есть какой то другой вариант как заносить это в базу данных в самом index.html в скрипте не используя бота?

Тогда пишите код на PHP, который будет записывать ваши числа в базу данных, а затем через бота подключайтесь к ней и смотрите, что получилось. Не уверен, в том, что в этом есть хоть какой-то смысл. Дело в том, что метод sendData() автоматически закрывает страницу, поэтому его необходимо использовать в последний момент.

Давайте тогда по другому, каким методом лучше воспользоваться, чтобы это через бота передавалось без сообщений в чат и без надобности выхода из веб страницы?

Базу данных нужно создавать, к которой будет обращаться скрипт и, бот будет осуществлять запросы и получать какую-то информацию.

да, но вот как это реализовать? как сделать связку такую с ботом, чтобы не было сообщений о передаче данных и они передавались сразу как только появлялся клик?

Уже вам отвечал, в базу данных отправляете, а затем просто закрываете окно без отправки данных через sendData().
